# Gstreamer-1.0 Error(No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I installed Gstreamer and all of the executable commands, including gstreamer-1.0, which are  located in "C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>", however the .c file ((basic-tutorial-1.c) i'm running the tutorials on is located in "C:\Users\jjohnson497-gtri\Documents\TrafficStop\Gstreamer_tutorials". When I run `gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`, I get the error :gcc.exe: error: gstreamer-1.0`: No such file or directory. How can I fix this? I tried adding "C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>" to the path environment variable, but I'm still getting that error. I am using Video Studio Code on windows if that helps.
You can find the tutorial page i'm following here: [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html?gi-language=c)